# echo javascript with single quotes

Tags: php, javascript, html

i got this thing

```
<?
if (mysql_num_rows($say) == 1) {
    $a = "cicişsin!"; 
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($say) == 0) {
    $a = "<a href='javascript:LaunchPopup('a2.php','250','1');'>ciciş yap</a>";
}
?>
```

but i cant echo second $a.. its exits at "javascript:LaunchPopup(" single quotes not shown

what can i do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$a = "<a href=\"javascript:LaunchPopup('a2.php','250','1');\">ciciş yap</a>";
```

Comment: Lets be proper: 
$a = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"LaunchPopup('a2.php','250','1');return false;\">ciciş yap</a>";

Comment: Beter, imho. $a = "<a href=\"a2.php\" onclick=\"LaunchPopup(this,'250','1');return false;\">cicis yap</a>"

Answer (score 3):

Never use `javascript:` URLs. Put the URL in the `href` attribute where it belongs:

```
$a= '<a href="a2.php" onclick="LaunchPopup(this.href, 250, 1); return false;">ciciş yap</a>';
```

Now not only do you not have to worry about the escaping (assuming you can get away with passing numbers as the other arguments), but also your link now works properly when middle-clicked or bookmarked, instead of giving a JavaScript error.

Better still, unobtrusive scripting:

```
<a href="a2.php" class="popup">ciciş yap</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
        if (document.links[i].className==='popup') {
            document.links[i].onclick= function() {
                LaunchPopup(this.href, '250', '1');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</a>
```

Keep script code in scripts and out of markup, then you don't have to worry about HTML-escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes like this

```
"<a href=\"javascript:LaunchPopup(\'a2.php\',\'250\',\'1\');\">ciciş yap</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes, something like this:

```
  $a = "<a href='javascript:LaunchPopup(\"a2.php\",\"250\",\"1\");'>ciciş yap</a>";
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$a = "<a href='javascript:LaunchPopup(a2.php,250,1)'>ciciş yap</a>";
```

**will work for you**

Comment: @Rubens Can U be specific as I am getting the "javascript:LaunchPopup(a2.php,250,1)" oon task bar onb hovering the link... I believe it will work.

Comment: `a2.php` (without that quotes) can't be recognized as string; when you run, you'll get: `'a2' is undefined`; click that link and you'll see it